Question about Infinite Series and Divergence Test
This is my first year as a high school calculus teacher, and on a recent exam (Created by my peers), there was this question:

The answer is E.  But wouldn't C also be true, because that would basically describe the divergence test? My teaching peers did not agree with me.  Any thoughts that could provide clarity?

You're right—that question (presumably unintentionally) has the two correct answers C and E.

C is true since if $lim_{n \to \infty}=\frac{a_n}{b_n}\neq 0$ the series diverges.
